# Retrieving new rowversion after INSERT using @@DBTS - is it safe?

Tags: sql-server, rowversion

It is common practice to pick up the newly created `IDENTITY` of a table using the `@@IDENTITY` variable after an `INSERT`.

Is it just equality correct to retrieve the last `rowversion` value following an `UPDATE` in a similar manner using the [`@@DBTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187366) value?

For example:

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('XXX') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE XXX
GO
CREATE TABLE XXX
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    RV rowversion
)
GO
INSERT INTO XXX(Name) VALUES 
    ('Apples'),('Bananas'),('Cranberries'),('Dragon Fruit'),('Eggplant'),('Fig'),('Grape')
GO
SELECT * FROM XXX
GO
UPDATE XXX
    SET Name = 'Chocolate' WHERE ID = 3
PRINT @@DBTS
GO
```

Now is `@@DBTS` safe from concurrent updates?

If another connection performs insert and updates between the `UPDATE` and the `PRINT`, would we end up with the `rowversion` of the 'other' connection rather than the one from our own update?

Comment: Using `@Identity` does not handle concurrency or consequent inserts happen within another scope (eg. in a trigger). Normally one would use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

Comment: `@@DBTS` is not safe for concurrent operations on database. you are not guaranteed that the version is related to your `insert/update/delete`

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected as much with `@@DBTS` but I didn't realise `@@IDENTITY` was also not thread safe.  I have some refactoring work to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN `@@DBTS`

> returns the last-used timestamp value of the current database

This means it is not thread safe.

You also should not use `@@IDENTITY`. `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY` return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session. However, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the value only within the current scope; `@@IDENTITY` is not limited to a specific scope. `@@IDENTITY` can for example return the wrong value if a trigger gets executed on  a table with an identity column.

Comment: So is my only option to pick up the new rowversion is to use an `OUTPUT` clause with `UPDATED.RV` (in the case of my example)?

Comment: Yes, using an `OUTPUT` clause is the most elegant solution.